# Access MySql Database using Intel Appframework

Tags: mysql, intel, appframework

My name is Putut.
I am currently working on a thesis to finish my lecture. I created an application using intel Appframework. Can anyone help me how to access MySQL with Intel Appframework? This is the login script of the application that I created using the Intel AppFramework.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/2.1/css/af.ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/2.1/css/icons.min.css">
    <title>Blank App Designer Project Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!--
      * The "meta viewport" tag (below) helps your app size appropriately to a device's screen.
      * Note that the meta viewport approach is being phased out in favor of the @viewport CSS  rule.
      * For a quick overview of both, see this article:
      * http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag
      * To see what happens, try the app on a real device with and without a "meta viewport" tag.
    -->

    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2"> -->

    <style>
        /* following three (cascaded) are equivalent to above three meta viewport statements */
        /* see http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/05/html5_dev_conf.html */
        /* see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/ */
            @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
            @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
            @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
            @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
            /*@-ms-viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }   
              @viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }*/
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">

    <!-- IMPORTANT: Do not include your weinre script tag as part of your release builds! -->
    <!-- Place your remote debugging (weinre) script URL from the Test tab here, if it does not work below -->
    <!-- <script src="http://debug-software.intel.com/target/target-script-min.js#insertabiglongfunkynumberfromthexdkstesttab"></script> -->

    <!-- Most third-party libraries should go here. References (below) are just examples to give you the general idea... -->
    <!-- <script src="lib/mc/hammer.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="lib/ft/fastclick.js"></script> -->

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK "legacy" container api calls -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- phantom library, needed for Cordova api calls -->
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
    <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK "legacy" container CORS -->

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- placeholder for custom event code, see file comments for details -->
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
    <!-- placeholder for custom init code, see file comments for details -->
    <script src="js/init-dev.js"></script>
    <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see file for details -->
    <!--                     
                    You may substitute jQuery for the App Framework selector library.
                    See http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_jquery
            -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="app_framework/2.1/appframework.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="app_framework/2.1/appframework.ui.js" data-ver="1"></script>
</head>

<body id="afui">

    <!-- IMPORTANT: Do not include your weinre script tag as part of your release builds! -->
    <!-- Place your remote debugging (weinre) script URL from the Test tab here, if it does not work above -->
    <!-- <script src="http://debug-software.intel.com/target/target-script-min.js#insertabiglongfunkynumberfromthexdkstesttab"></script> -->
       <div class="uwrap" id="content">
           <div class="upage panel" id="mainpage" data-header="af-header-0" data-footer="none">
               <div class="upage-outer">
                   <header class="container-group inner-element uib_w_1" data-uib="app_framework/header" data-ver="1" id="af-header-0">
                       <h1>Login User</h1>
                       <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                       <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left">   </div>
                       <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right">   </div>
                   </header>
                   <div class="upage-content" id="mainsub">

                       <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_1 row-height-1" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                           <div class="col uib_col_1 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                               <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                                   <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_2 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="1">
                                       <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="usrname">Username</label>
                                       <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" id="usrname">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="1">
                                       <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="passwd">Password</label>
                                       <input class="wide-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="passwd">
                                   </div><a class="button widget uib_w_4 d-margins icon user" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="submitButton">Login</a><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- /upage-content -->

               </div>
               <!-- /upage-outer -->

           </div>
           <!-- /upage -->

       </div>
       <!-- /uwrap -->
   </body>

</html>
```

and this is my database script

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.10.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 19, 2014 at 11:21 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.51
-- PHP Version: 5.2.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

-- 
-- Database: `login`
-- 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `loginuser`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `loginuser` (
`id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `loginuser`
-- 

INSERT INTO `loginuser` VALUES (1, 'andre', '1142b33e04');
INSERT INTO `loginuser` VALUES (2, 'michael', '1706b3c726');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you will need a WebService to access your Mysql database, it can be implemented in PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, etc.

This is a simple workflow.

Your mobile app do a request to this Webservice;

The Webservice backend access Mysql e verify if the user exists;

The Webservice returns a reponse with an Success or Fail;

Your mobile app receive that response (Json is prefered),  shows a message to the user or whatever you want.

The framework provides a basic method (Android and IPhone only).
Take a look to this link.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493048